# initMouseEvent not working as expected in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

The following test page submits a form by simulating a mouse click on an image submit button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <title></title>  
    <script type="text/javascript">              
        function clickIt()
        {
            var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            clickEvent.initMouseEvent(
            'click', true, true, window, 0,
            0, 0, 10, 10, false, false,
            false, false, 0, null
            );            
            document.getElementById("post").dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.html" method="GET">        
        <input id="post" name="post" value="hello" type="image">
    </form>
    <button onclick="clickIt()">Click It</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When clicking the "Click It" button, Chrome correctly navigates to:

http://localhost:57488/test.html?post.x=2&post.y=2&post=hello

IE11 navigates to:

http://localhost:57488/test.html?post.x=0&post.y=0

I somehow need to set the x and y coordinates, but it's just not working in IE. IE11 always sets the coordinates to zero. Does anyone know how this can be done in IE11?